# How to draw one line only one time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I'm using `GDI+` to visualize the schema of some user-specified building.
There are no complex objects in it - all of them can be represented by rectangles.
I do it, but have one issue: many rectangles are overlap, e.g. then rooms are adjacent.
So some lines drawed many times!
This looks bad (fat line) and decrease the application performance (extra work).

Is there a way to draw each line only once on a screen?

My code (simplified) looks like this:

```
 private void Visualizator_Paint( object sender, PaintEventArgs e )
 {
        if ( m_building == null ) return;

        var g = e.Graphics;

        // Smooth graphics output and scale
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        ScaleGraphics( g );

        ...

        foreach( var room in m_rooms )
        {
            RectangleF extent = room.Extent;
            g.DrawRectangle( brownPen, extent.X, extent.Y, extent.Width, extent.Height );
        }

        ...
  }

  void ScaleGraphics( Graphics g )
  {
        // Set margins inside the control client area in pixels
        var margin = new Margins( 16, 16, 16, 16 );

        // Set the domain of (x,y) values
        var range = m_building.Extents;

        // Make it smaller by 5%
        range.Inflate( 0.05f * range.Width, 0.05f * range.Height );

        // Scale graphics
        ScaleGraphics( g, Visualizator, range, margin );
  }

  void ScaleGraphics( Graphics g, Control control, RectangleF domain, Margins margin )
    {
        // Find the drawable area in pixels (control-margins)
        int W = control.Width - margin.Left - margin.Right;
        int H = control.Height - margin.Bottom - margin.Top;

        // Ensure drawable area is at least 1 pixel wide
        W = Math.Max( 1, W );
        H = Math.Max( 1, H );

        // Find the origin (0,0) in pixels
        float OX = margin.Left - W * ( domain.Left / domain.Width );
        float OY = margin.Top + H * ( 1 + domain.Top / domain.Height );

        // Find the scale to fit the control
        float SX = W / domain.Width;
        float SY = H / domain.Height;

        // Transform the Graphics scene
        if ( m_panPoint.IsEmpty )
            m_panPoint = new PointF( OX, OY );

        g.TranslateTransform( m_panPoint.X, m_panPoint.Y, MatrixOrder.Append );
        g.ScaleTransform( SX * m_scale, -SY * m_scale );
    }
```

Screenshot of defect: [image: antialias consequences]

Comment: I can not understand what is your problem. but you can Clear before drawing rextangles g.Clear(Color.) Plus better use double buffering

Comment: @qwr Many of rectangles (rooms) are adjacent, so some (many) lines draw more than once. I want to draw such "shared" lines only time.

Comment: Performance is not an issue, believe me. If those line get fat the rooms probably should be drawn in slightly different positions, don't you think? What Pen width do you use? Can you upload an image of the problem? You could try to create a room class that cooperates with other rooms to actually change the drawing as you write in your title, but that'll be a lot of work. Fitting everything properly on a pixel raster seems easier, I'd say.

Comment: Anti-aliasing is the core problem, the aliasing pixels get messed up when a line is over-drawn since it treats the existing ones from a previous line as background.  That disturbs the visual effect and makes the line look too fat.  Not exactly a trivial problem to solve, corner cases where only a part of a line coincides and the lines don't overlap in the world model but do (partly) overlap in the view are the tricky ones to solve.  Doing the culling is a quadratic algorithm, that hurts.  Turning off anti-aliasing is the only quick fix.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, disabling antialias really helps.
However, there can i read more about this issue and way to solve it?
My thoughts: store all lines in one global unique-items container (like C++ std::set), and draw it instead of rooms themselfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce the blurring/smearing effect described in the question. However, the basic request to be able to avoid over-drawing lines seems reasonably clear and not terribly complicated to address. So I offer this class which can do that work:

```
/// <summary>
/// Consolidates horizontal and vertical lines.
/// </summary>
class LineConsolidator : IEnumerable<LineConsolidator.Line>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A pair of points defining a line
    /// </summary>
    public struct Line
    {
        public Point Start { get; private set; }
        public Point End { get; private set; }

        public Line(Point start, Point end)
            : this()
        {
            Start = start;
            End = end;
        }
    }

    private struct Segment
    {
        public int Start { get; private set; }
        public int End { get; private set; }

        public Segment(int start, int end)
            : this()
        {
            if (end < start)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("start must be less than or equal to end");
            }

            Start = start;
            End = end;
        }

        public Segment Union(Segment other)
        {
            if (End < other.Start || other.End < Start)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Only overlapping segments may be consolidated");
            }

            return new Segment(
                    Math.Min(Start, other.Start),
                    Math.Max(End, other.End));
        }

        public Segment? Intersect(Segment other)
        {
            int start = Math.Max(Start, other.Start),
                end = Math.Min(End, other.End);

            if (end < start)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return new Segment(start, end);
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<int, List<Segment>> _horizontalLines = new Dictionary<int, List<Segment>>();
    private Dictionary<int, List<Segment>> _verticalLines = new Dictionary<int, List<Segment>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Add horizontal line
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="y">The Y coordinate of the line to add</param>
    /// <param name="start">The first X coordinate of the line to add (must not be larger than <paramref name="end"/></param>
    /// <param name="end">The second X coordinate of the line to add (must not be smaller than <paramref name="start"/></param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method submits a new horizontal line to the collection. It is merged with any other
    /// horizontal lines with exactly the same Y coordinate that it overlaps.
    /// </remarks>
    public void AddHorizontal(int y, int start, int end)
    {
        _AddLine(y, new Segment(start, end), _horizontalLines);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add vertical line
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="y">The X coordinate of the line to add</param>
    /// <param name="start">The first Y coordinate of the line to add (must not be larger than <paramref name="end"/></param>
    /// <param name="end">The second Y coordinate of the line to add (must not be smaller than <paramref name="start"/></param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method submits a new vertical line to the collection. It is merged with any other
    /// vertical lines with exactly the same X coordinate that it overlaps.
    /// </remarks>
    public void AddVertical(int x, int start, int end)
    {
        _AddLine(x, new Segment(start, end), _verticalLines);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add all four sides of a rectangle as individual lines
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rect">The rectangle containing the lines to add</param>
    public void AddRectangle(Rectangle rect)
    {
        AddHorizontal(rect.Top, rect.Left, rect.Right);
        AddHorizontal(rect.Bottom, rect.Left, rect.Right);
        AddVertical(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Bottom);
        AddVertical(rect.Right, rect.Top, rect.Bottom);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all of the horizontal lines in the collection
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Line> HorizontalLines
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var kvp in _horizontalLines)
            {
                foreach (var segment in kvp.Value)
                {
                    yield return new Line(new Point(segment.Start, kvp.Key), new Point(segment.End, kvp.Key));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all of the vertical lines in the collection
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Line> VerticalLines
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var kvp in _verticalLines)
            {
                foreach (var segment in kvp.Value)
                {
                    yield return new Line(new Point(kvp.Key, segment.Start), new Point(kvp.Key, segment.End));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void _AddLine(int lineKey, Segment newSegment, Dictionary<int, List<Segment>> segmentKeyToSegments)
    {
        // Get the list of segments for the given key (X for vertical lines, Y for horizontal lines)
        List<Segment> segments;

        if (!segmentKeyToSegments.TryGetValue(lineKey, out segments))
        {
            segments = new List<Segment>();
            segmentKeyToSegments[lineKey] = segments;
        }

        int isegmentInsert = 0, isegmentMergeFirst = -1, ilineSegmentLast = -1;

        // Find all existing segments that should be merged with the new one
        while (isegmentInsert < segments.Count && segments[isegmentInsert].Start <= newSegment.End)
        {
            Segment? intersectedSegment = newSegment.Intersect(segments[isegmentInsert]);

            if (intersectedSegment != null)
            {
                // If they overlap, merge them together, keeping track of all the existing
                // segments which were merged
                newSegment = newSegment.Union(segments[isegmentInsert]);

                if (isegmentMergeFirst == -1)
                {
                    isegmentMergeFirst = isegmentInsert;
                }

                ilineSegmentLast = isegmentInsert;
            }

            isegmentInsert++;
        }

        if (isegmentMergeFirst == -1)
        {
            // If there was no merge, just insert the new segment
            segments.Insert(isegmentInsert, newSegment);
        }
        else
        {
            // If more than one segment was merged, remove all but one
            if (ilineSegmentLast > isegmentMergeFirst)
            {
                segments.RemoveRange(isegmentMergeFirst + 1, ilineSegmentLast - isegmentMergeFirst);
            }

            // Copy the new, merged segment back to the first original segment's slot
            segments[isegmentMergeFirst] = newSegment;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<LineConsolidator.Line> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return HorizontalLines.Concat(VerticalLines).GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Note that this is based on integer coordinates. It's a little trickier to apply this sort of logic to floating point coordinates, if one is actually concerned about accommodating round-off error. But if the floating point coordinates are assured of always coming from the same source when they overlap, then they will meet the equality condition this implementation requires and you can just change the types to floating point.

I included the properties to retrieve just the horizontal or vertical lines, so that I could draw them differently from each other (different line end-caps) to verify the algorithm was working. Normally I think you'd just enumerate the whole collection when drawing.

You use it by first creating an empty instance of the collection, then adding your rectangles (or individual lines if desired) via the `AddRectangle()` method, then finally enumerating all of the resulting lines.

I would expect this to perform just fine up to thousands of lines or so. In my tests, I just recreated the collection from scratch every time I painted the window.

It might perform well enough even at higher magnitudes depending on the PC, but I didn't try to do any specific optimizations, opting instead for easy-to-understand code. In a situation where you're dealing with an extremely large number of rectangles, you might want to keep a persistent instance to collect lines/rectangles as they are generated. Then you don't have to regenerate it every paint event. That may or may not then require adding features to the class to support removal of lines.

Comment: Oh, thanks for a huge amount of work!
I will try your code (and show the problem screenshot) on weekends.
They are fortunely 4 days long :D
P.S. I can add link to my GitGub repo, all my code is open source

Comment: I added problem screenshot to OP post.

Comment: My data contains floating point rectangles.
So, i must implement "tricky" logic? :)

Comment: I don't know...like I said, it depends on where those floating point values come from. The code as written depends on equality to collect lines that should be merged. If your code generates those values in a way such that either there's no rounding error (e.g. the value is computed once and then assigned to all of the lines in the same place) or the rounding error is always the same (e.g. each position that's the same will go through exactly the same computation), then you might get away without it. Otherwise, you'll have to quantize the coordinates, so that they _can_ be compared via equality

Comment: Ok, i got it. My building coords came from the data file, they are not changed during application lifetime. Moving building looks like strange :)

Comment: Also i "port" your code to the float coords. Screenshot of the result: http://i.imgur.com/xT6SeZQ.png?1

Comment: P.S. GDI+ DrawLine method look like very slow oO
I don't remember such drawing lags with rectangles drawing

Comment: It shouldn't be that slow. How many lines are you drawing? Your sample image has only about a dozen lines which would draw almost instantly on any modern PC. Also, is it the drawing that's slow? Or the initialization of the line-merging data? I did mention I hadn't done any particular optimizations there...one things you might try is to build the data just once, and then reuse the object when painting.

Comment: Lol, i just forgot to remove `Console.WriteLine` statements :D
They are extremely slow down the program run speed.
To cache lines is good advice, i will try it.

Comment: And the last question: how scaling the scene will influence to my "blur" effect?
maybe i need additional hacking with scaling code...

Comment: `How would scaling influence the "blur" effect?` I'm not entirely sure what you mean. But I can tell you that in my attempt to reproduce the smearing/blurring you described, I added scaling to my test program and I saw no effect on the final output. A scale factor > 1 might make the blurring worse (by making the whole image larger so defects are more noticeable), or it might make it better (if the extent of the blurring becomes a smaller proportion of the overall image, as the image is enlarged). Likewise scale factor < 1 could also go either way. You'll just have to test it.